# Calling a function from functions.php in header

Tags: functions

Been searching a lot for how to call a function in header.php where the function is in functions.php.

How do I solve this?

I have my function in functions.php like this:

```
function testFunction()
{
echo "This is a test";
}
```

Comment: you just call it in your `header.php` like that: `<?php testFunction();?>`. That's all

Comment: This looks like a pure PHP question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! just call it `testFunction();` wherever you want between php tags.

*But not a wp question*

Comment: Since this relates to the WordPress header and function files, surely this is a WP specific concern?

Comment: This was about how to call a function within a set of files which OP obviously didn't hesitate to try basic things. Not wordpress specific. @AdamMcquiff

Comment: In case someone wants a better answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341965/calling-a-function-from-functions-php-in-custom-page-blog-post?rq=1