# Calling a function from functions.php in custom page/ blog post

Tags: plugin-development, functions, pages, page-template

Is it possible to call a function from functions.php in custom page or blog post?

I put simple function in functions.php:

```
function testTest()
{
echo "Test";
}
```

And called it from the page:

```
<?php testTest();?>
```

But it doesn't work. Do I need to make a plugin to use simple function like that inside one chosen custom page?

Thanks for your answer,
Mary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [add_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) if you want to use it within the editor.

```
function footag_func() {
    return "Test";
}
add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
```

And then use [footag] in your editor.

Or

Use code like this in functions.php and add a conditional tag

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'your_function' );
function your_function() {
if ( is_singular('post') ) {
    echo 'Test';
    }
}
```

or

Create a function in functions.php

```
function your_function() {
return 'Test';

}
```

And then use this in your template

```
echo your_function();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check all of the versions. I upvoted, but unfortunately it doesn't show because I'm a new user. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly create a quick shortcode for doing that.

`add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'my_test_callback' );`

Then, in the callback function you do this:

```
function my_test_callback() {
    //start adding the echoed content to the output buffer
    ob_start();

    //run your code here - in this case your testTest() function
    testTest();

    //return the output buffer
    //NOTE: directly echoing the content will give unexpected results
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then, in your content pages you just add `[test_shortcode]` and it will run your PHP function.

For a better view on shortcodes here are some useful links:

[Official Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

[A nice tool for creating shortcodes](https://generatewp.com/shortcodes/)

[An article I wrote on how to build shortcodes](https://www.cornelraiu.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-shortcode/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check that. I upvoted, but unfortunately it doesn't show because I'm a new user.

Comment: no worries. hope that helped :)

Comment: Hi @CornelRaiu - Is there a way to create a normal link on frontend, that upon clicking, runs "test_shortcode" or "my_test_callback()" function?

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri you should make use of AJAX for that. Make an on click listener on the button that will trigger an AJAX action and then output the response